# Attach file in MB51 with GOS objects programmatically

Tags: attachment, abap, saprfc, bapi

Im working on creating a material document movement (MB51 report) and then attaching document to it.
So far Im finished with creating the document and returning the document number.

And now I need to attach file to that document.
I was not able to find out which BAPI does this...

so can I kindly ask you, which BAPI can let me upload the file from my drive to the object?
[image]

I want to do the same in code which I do by that way:

**SERVICES FOR OBJECT > CREATE > CREATE ATTACHMENT**

Please note Im looking for a remote way to do this, therefore ARCHIVOBJECT_CREATE_FILE FunctionModule is out of question :(

Answer (score -2):

you can use the function module ARCHIV_CONNECTION_INSERT. I hope this is fine instead of a BAPI.
There is a SAP-blog-post with further discription.

https://blogs.sap.com/2018/04/22/programmatically-create-and-retrieve-documents-attached-in-gos-generic-object-services-via-stored-business-document./

Comment: Link only answers are discouraged. Provide working code snippet with explanation

Comment: ARCHIVOBJECT_CREATE_FILE gives exception CALL_FUNCTION_NOT_REMOTE, sorry, I should of mention im accessing via RFC